# Java - Removing tag from xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have an xml, as follows:

```
<Row ss:Index="76" ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="25">
   <Cell ss:Index="1" ss:MergeAcross="9" ss:StyleID="s38">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
          <Font html:Size="15" html:Face="Times New Roman" x:Family="Roman" html:Color="#000000">
            <B> ABCD </B>
          </Font>
       </ss:Data>
   </Cell>
</Row>
```

Now, I want to remove the < B > tag, but retain the content, "ABCD" here. Or is there a way to remove the < B > from the whole XML file using java. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I am not getting anything that can delete only the tag, retaining its content in Java.

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: @EvgenyLebedev I couldn't find any relative resource for this. Like there is strip_tags() function in python lxml. Please help with Java.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Parse document with [DOM4J](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom4j_parse_document.htm) or [SAX Parser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_sax_parse_document.htm)
2. Get value from `Font` tag

`<Font html:Size="15" html:Face="Times New Roman" x:Family="Roman" html:Color="#000000">
<B> ABCD </B>
</Font>`

3. Remove all html tags from value

[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)-way

```
Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

String replaceAll-way:

```
replaceAll("\<(\/)?B\>","")
```

4. Set new value to XML Font tag